# which is faster when application is running in java?

Tags: java

which is faster when application is running in java?

this:

```
static void readPrice(String dir) throws Exception{
    /*Make URL and Connection*/
    URL url = new URL(dir + "/prices/all/");
    HttpURLConnection connection;

    /*Start connection*/
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    /*Send User-Agent*/
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", user_agent);

    /*Get http response*/
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line = rd.readLine();

    strJson = line;
    /*Read the prices json*/
    pricesJson( strJson );

}
```

or this:

```
static void readPrice(String dir) throws Exception{
    /*Connection with url */
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(
            dir + "/prices/all/").openConnection();
    /*Send User-Agent*/
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", user_agent);
    /*Read the prices json*/
    pricesJson( new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream())).readLine() );

}
```

I need application very quickly and smoothly, because it has to make requests to the server in real time

Comment: This is more or less the same. The compiler will turn these into the equivalent byte code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you don't check yourself?

Just add two timestamps at the begining and end of the code and calculate the time difference easily (in milliseconds). Then, you can check, which code executes in shortest time and if there is any significant difference.

```
//Place at the beginning of the code
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//Place at the end of the code
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println(" Execution  Time: " + (startTime-endTime));
```

Answer (score 1):

Inlining statements doesn't improve the generated code. All you saved are some newline characters in the input source file...

It may even yield the same bytecode.

The **most reliable** estimation of performance is **benchmarking**. Compilers change. Code changes. You rarely know what is faster, until you have benchmarked alternatives.

Beware of **premature optimization**!

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming.
>
> -- Donald Knuth, Computer Programming as an Art (1974)